# Is not changing "http://tempuri.org/" reference is just lack of professionalism or more?

Tags: .net, web-services, namespaces

Is the reason to change **"http://tempuri.org/"** default  reference in any web service is merely for :

> 1 : Showing that I understand namespaces.
>
> 2 : For the sake of showing professionalism.

If it is not giving any ***benefit in technical aspect***,

why should we go ahead and change it, which might end up showing some errors for a few.

Comment: This is where "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" would apply. There's nothing wrong with keeping it as tempuri.

Comment: Random anecdote: every time I read "temprui", in my head, I think of Chicken Tempura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said much about your web service, but typically namespaces are only useful when combined with an XSD. If you are using an XSD, then namespaces are useful for the same reason that they are useful in C-style languages (C#, Java, C++) - to differentiate your "classes" from other programs.

If a consumer of your webservice is trying to build a mashup with another webservice and that programmer needs to combine the XML from your service with the XML from another service, then those namespaces begin to become really important (especially if the other webservice has, like yours, chosen not to change the namespace from the default).

Or, more succinctly:

> *An XML instance may contain element or attribute names from more than one XML vocabulary. If each vocabulary is given a namespace, the ambiguity between identically named elements or attributes can be resolved.*
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

On a personal note, I find the naming of an XML namespace as an opportunity to differentiate my code from the crowd. Taking the time and care to give your code a proper name gives other professionals the impression that you've taken the time and care to code properly. Think of it this way: if you had an API with a function named `fUnctiontodoSomeThin()`, you may be pleased with its functionality but part of you is going to wonder why the programmer didn't take the time and effort to spell and use capitalization correctly/consistently. Perhaps s/he didn't take the time to wrap their database call in a try/catch block? It might cause me to go looking for another API (all else being equal, of course).

Comment: Why would wrapping a database call in a try catch block when you are not going to handle the error be a mistake?

Comment: @TomasZubiri Huh? It's a random and arbitrary example on a 5 year old post. How about... "Perhaps s/he didn't take the time to reject the returned Promise on an error."

Answer (score 2):

We use namespaces as a way to signal to client applications that the service contract or data contract has made a breaking change between releases (i.e. The return type has changed, the order of the parameters have changed, etc).  Otherwise your client applications will continue to attempt to parse the returned values as if they were in the old contract.  The parsing will fail with a convoluted and difficult to understand error message.  Or worse yet, the parsing could succeed with swapped values (i.e. change the order of two string properties in data contract).

More information on [WCF Service Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx).